# In Python I put print() but still get a syntax error

Tags: python, syntax-error

I read some answers here about print() parentheses. I have put them and get syntax error anyway. Can you tell why?

```
Python 3.3.2+ (default, Feb 28 2014, 00:52:16) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux



>>> answer = "no"
>>> while answer == "no":
...     answer = input("Are we there? ")
... print("We're there!")
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    print("We're there!")
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Yes, I can see the ... prompt keeps the print line under while loop. If I press 2 times Enter it prints the string from input.

```
>>> answer = "no"
>>> while answer == "no":
...     answer = input("Are we there? ")
... 
Are we there?
```

Comment: if you get an error for a correct line of code, the line above is the problem, while using the CLI, press enter another time to end the while loop and then type in ither lines of code

Answer (score 7):

Well since you're in the interpreter, you can see the 3 dots again, which means it's still expecting it to be under the while loop. Just press enter again and it will work. But if you want the print to be a part of the loop, indent it, press enter and press enter again. Hope this helps!

```
1: >>> answer = "no"
2: >>> while answer == "no":
3: ...     answer = input("Are we there? ")
4: ... 
5: Are we there? no
6: Are we there? yes
7: >>>
```

At line 2, you start the loop.
At line 3, you say the input from stdin will be stored in `answer`. But the argument that input takes is what message will be prompted to used.
At line 4, interpreter still expects something from the loop. If you have an indented block, it is part of the loop. If you press enter, it finishes the loop

NOTE: This is an interpreter and it has now the whole `while` block which can be executed, so it executes.

At line 5, it is executing the loop and waiting for your input(and has also shown the correct message)

You enter `'no'` as the input.
It doesn't break the loop so it executes the loop again and asks input again. Now put `'no'` and it breaks out and you have the prompt again as the interpreter has nothing to execute (yet).

Comment: When I press enter the second time it outputs the line   
Are we there?

Comment: @vincent since you're in the interpreter, you can't run both statements at once! It's going to run the `while` loop because that's all one "block" of code, but you can't put anything after it. Try wrapping the whole thing in a function and then calling the function.

Comment: Yes, because it's running the loop now. When you enter `'no'` then it breaks out and then you can run the next line. Keep in mind that this is an interpreter and it executes as soon as it has something it can execute!

Comment: @vincent You need to either run it as a script or put that while loop into a function.

Comment: Thanks to all of you!